# exporting html table with links to csv

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to export a table to a csv file for our users to export a copy of their purchases to a format they can use in quickbooks, excel, etc.

The function works great, except that the first column of our table contains urls and these columns appear blank in the export.

I am wondering how i could modify this so when a link is encountered as a field the text of that link would be added to the csv.

Example: `<a href="example.php">an example</a>` would add `an example` to the csv for that field.

```
        function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
            var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row), $cols = $row.find('td,th');
                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col), text = $col.text();
                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes
                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);
            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim).split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim).split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
            console.log(csv);

            if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([csv],
                {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"}),
                "csvname.csv")
            } else {
                $(this).attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': csvData, 'target': '_blank' });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your snippet should already support this. It iterates over all rows of the table and for each row over all of its column fields, where jQuery's [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function is applied in order to extract the text. This should return the text between a tags as well.

Example:

```js
console.log($('<td><a href="test.html">Test page</a></td>').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

will return the string `Test page`.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9zu0wa8/) contains the function you provided and a dummy table with some anchor elements. In my opinion it already meets your requirements.

Comment: seems you are correct, for some reason excel has an issue importing our first column - can't figure out why. Works perfectly when I import to google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://example.php";
a.append("an example"); 
document.body.appendChild(a);

console.log(a.textContent);
```